# How to solve "jupyter_client.kernelspec.NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named iqsharp" in python?

Tags: python-3.x, quantum-computing, q#

I was trying to print hello world in Microsoft's Q#.
When I ran the code It's shows like this.
Even I installed the package. I don't know where the problem is.
I think it's in jupyter notebook's permission or something.
Thanks for your help.

Here is my simple code

```
   import qsharp
   from HelloWorld import SayHello
   SayHello.simulate()
```

Here is my output

```
  File "d:\Program Files\Quantum Projects\hello_quantum.py", line 1, in <module>
    import qsharp
  File "C:\Users\ELCOT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\qsharp\__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
    client = _start_client()
  File "C:\Users\ELCOT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\qsharp\clients\__init__.py", line 28, in _start_client
    client.start()
  File "C:\Users\ELCOT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\qsharp\clients\iqsharp.py", line 75, in start
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(extra_arguments=["--user-agent", f"qsharp.py{user_agent_extra}"])
  File "C:\Users\ELCOT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 246, in start_kernel
    kernel_cmd = self.format_kernel_cmd(extra_arguments=extra_arguments)
  File "C:\Users\ELCOT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 170, in format_kernel_cmd
    cmd = self.kernel_spec.argv + extra_arguments
  File "C:\Users\ELCOT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 82, in kernel_spec
    self._kernel_spec = self.kernel_spec_manager.get_kernel_spec(self.kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\ELCOT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\kernelspec.py", line 236, in get_kernel_spec
    raise NoSuchKernel(kernel_name)
jupyter_client.kernelspec.NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named iqsharp
```

Comment: It looks like perhaps the IQ# Jupyter kernel is not installed. Can you follow the instructions here to see if it helps? https://learn.microsoft.com/quantum/quickstarts/install-python

Comment: I already installed that. But it's still showing this error. Do I have to change any jupyter notebook environment?

Comment: How did you install IQ#? Did you use `dotnet tool install` followed by `dotnet iqsharp install`? What does `dotnet iqsharp --version` report? And how about `pip show qsharp`?

Comment: If you continue to have issues, consider using the `qsharp` conda package, as it avoids a lot of the manual installation steps such as the ones you're trying. See the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/quantum/quickstarts/install-python.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue when setting my conda environment from a script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
. $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
# assumes you followed this doc and have run:
# conda create -n qsharp-env -c quantum-engineering qsharp notebook
conda activate qsharp-env
```

I solved it by installing IQ# as instructed by [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quickstarts/install-python?tabs=tabid-dotnetcli) (slightly different from Ryan Shaffer's comment):

```
dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp
dotnet iqsharp install
```

I was then able to run `python -c "import qsharp"` and more complex Python programs.